# Override function name as object name in returned results when using "with" in Eloquent query?

Tags: database, function, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Is there any way of overriding the relationship function name as the object name when returning results of an Eloquent query that uses a "with" modifier on the query?

For example:

```
public function myShifts()
{
    $user_id = Input::get('user_id');
    $user = User::find($user_id);

    $shifts = $user
                ->shifts()
                ->with('reservations.user')
                ->select('id', 'user_id', 'seats', 'start', 'end')
                ->orderBy('start')
                ->get();

    return Response::json($shifts);
}
```

Is using a nested relationship with a reservations function and a user function belonging to my Shift model.

This returns data (that when put into JSON) looks like:

```
[
{
    "id": "56",
    "user_id": "1",
    "seats": "3",
    "start": "2015-03-07 18:00:00",
    "end": "2015-03-07 19:00:00",
    "reservations": [
        {
            "id": "94",
            "user_id": null,
            "shift_id": "56",
            "passengers": null,
            "origin": null,
            "destination": null,
            "pickup_time": "2015-03-07 18:00:00",
            "user": null
        },
        {
            "id": "95",
            "user_id": null,
            "shift_id": "56",
            "passengers": null,
            "origin": null,
            "destination": null,
            "pickup_time": "2015-03-07 18:15:00",
            "user": null
        },
        {
            "id": "96",
            "user_id": null,
            "shift_id": "56",
            "passengers": null,
            "origin": null,
            "destination": null,
            "pickup_time": "2015-03-07 18:30:00",
            "user": null
        },
        {
            "id": "97",
            "user_id": null,
            "shift_id": "56",
            "passengers": null,
            "origin": null,
            "destination": null,
            "pickup_time": "2015-03-07 18:45:00",
            "user": null
        }
    ]
}
]
```

As you can see, the name of the function "reservations" becomes the name of the object in my results. Is there any way this can be overridden so that I can call it something else?

Ultimately, I am trying to create two relationship functions that find reservations based on whether or not the reservation has a null `user_id` or a populated `user_id`, however the function name becoming the object name in my results is not acceptable.

ALTERNATIVELY, can I have a single, generic relationship function and then pass a where condition to it when I use it in my query with the `with` component?

Apologies if I am not explaining things clearly. My brain is wracked from toying with this all day.

EDIT

For example, changing my reservations() function over to "madeReservations()" returns this:

```
[
{
    "id": "58",
    "user_id": "1",
    "seats": "3",
    "start": "2015-03-08 18:00:00",
    "end": "2015-03-08 19:00:00",
    "shifts": null,
    "made_reservations": [
        {
            "id": "102",
            "user_id": null,
            "shift_id": "58",
            "passengers": null,
            "origin": null,
            "destination": null,
            "pickup_time": "2015-03-08 18:00:00",
            "user": null
        },
        {
            "id": "103",
            "user_id": null,
            "shift_id": "58",
            "passengers": null,
            "origin": null,
            "destination": null,
            "pickup_time": "2015-03-08 18:15:00",
            "user": null
        },
        {
            "id": "105",
            "user_id": null,
            "shift_id": "58",
            "passengers": null,
            "origin": null,
            "destination": null,
            "pickup_time": "2015-03-08 18:45:00",
            "user": null
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
class Shift {

    protected $hidden = ['reservations'];

    protected $appends = ['shifts'];

    public function reservations()
    {
        // you know what to do here...
    }

    public function getShiftsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->reservations;
    }

}
```

```php
$user->shifts()
      ->with('reservations.user')
      ->select('id', 'user_id', 'seats', 'start', 'end')
      ->orderBy('start')
      ->get();
```

Comment: Can you explain how that works, for future reference? Ie.  why do you use the getShiftsAttribute(), the $hidden, as well as the setAppends()?

Comment: Also, I tried your answer and got a "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::setAppends()"... Any ideas? I certainly appreciate your help.

Comment: Ok. Now it works, however now it returns "shifts" as the object name instead of "reservations". Let's say I rename my reservations() function to "madeReservations()", can I make that return the object name as "reservations" instead of "shifts"? That's really what I'm trying to accomplish, as I need two different reservations() functions, one that returns on a whereNull condition and one that returns on a wherNotNull() condition.